# How do Ethereum ERC-20 Contracts for Tokens Interact

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Learning Solidity along with token development.

I'm having a hard time understanding how tokens with multiple smart contracts interact with each other.

I've read through other tokens with multiple contracts on GitHub and reviewed contracts on OpenZeppelin but they all appear somewhat orphaned.

Let's say we developed a token that has a supply and tracks wallet address to amount using a map. The contract is released and is given an address. Admin or privilege methods are protected via owner address validation. Then we release a second contract that needs to make apply a fee for transactions.

How does the second (token transaction fees) contract interact with the data stored on the first (token contract)? Does the second contract need to also verify ownership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any contract on Ethereum can interact with any other contract by using Interfaces. You can call methods from the second contract on the first contract for an ERC20 token as below:

1. Define ERC20 Interface

```
interface ERC20 {
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
}
```

2. Use the interface and token contract address to call methods on the first contract:

```
ERC20(tokenContractAddress).balanceOf(0xabcd....);
```

The similar approach can be used for any contracts

Comment: so then custom rbac logic prevents me from writing a contract that extracts tokens from other accounts?

Comment: You can only call the methods of a contract you are permitted to call. If you check the ERC20 contract, there is no method that allows you to extract tokens from other accounts. If someone deploys a scam ERC20 contract that allows the contract owner to extract tokens from other accounts, then yes it is possible.

Comment: What determines who can execute methods on a contract or a contract that calls another contract?

Comment: The code determines. There are multiple ways to determine access control. In ERC20, the contract is designed in such a way that you can transfer tokens only from your balance. Other ways to limit who can call a method is by using "require" checks for a certain address or condition, function modifiers, or by using advanced Access Control contracts by Openzeppelin

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I thought there were more built-in mechanisms like "only contract owner" but have now found there isn't. It's up to the contract to enforce AC. Thanks!